# When using a batch file, 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file, npm

I have grunt, jshint, bower, etc. installed via `npm install [x]` on my machine. Each of them is a file visible in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

When I open a Command Prompt and type in jshint, grunt, etc., each of them runs as expected. In addition, my PATH includes `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

However, when I run a .bat file that calls any of them, I get `'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` All the other commands (PATH, where grunt) work correctly in the batch file, and even produce the same results.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: Stick set at top of batch file and see what are the variables in that execution of cmd. Also while it's running type somewhere else `wmic process get` and what commandline is your batch started with. How do you start your batch?

Comment: For clarification, other commands does not include `jshint`, `bower` or any other npm installed command. None of the npm installed commands work.

Comment: Aha! This line in the batch file caused it: `set PATH=C:\Python26\;C:\Python27\;%PATH%`. What's wrong with this line though? Should it not end in slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to this problem:

```
set PATH=C:\Python26\;C:\Python27\;%PATH%
set PATH=C:\Python26;C:\Python27;%PATH%
```

**Both** of these lines will break pathing in a batch file. To get it to work, put the path at the end:

```
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python26;C:\Python27
endlocal
```

(Also, setlocal/endlocal isn't necessary but it's good practice)